# How to create a vagrant box in a remote server

Tags: virtual-machines, ansible, vagrant

I've been using vagrant since a few months to test server configurations (with ansible).

At work we have some spare internal servers that I would like to use for our continuous integration system.

Is there a way that just like you can do `vagrant up` and you get a locally running virtualbox VM, you can do the same but creating that VM on a different server?

So far we are creating VMs on our servers via `vmbuilder` and I would like to replace it with something up-to-date, as I'm familiar with vagrant I would like to stick with for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an old [vagrant module](https://github.com/robparrott/ansible-vagrant) for ansible in GitHub that might still work, but seems to be unmaintained. If you have interest enough in going this route, you might want to revamp it.

Other than that, you can still use the [`command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html) module.